# tried to remove the item from the cart but the code is not working

Tags: php, session, multidimensional-array

in this index_to_remove is coming via a hidden input type in the form...
i created a form with a remove button and via a hidden output field i passed the index of item that i want to remove from the cart and implemented this code.But its not working.......

```
     <?php
         /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // if user wants to remove an item from cart
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     if(isset($_POST['index_to_remove']) && $_POST['index_to_remove']="" )
      {
      //access the array and rum code to remove that array index
        $key_to_remove=$_POST['index_to_remove'];
              if(count($_SESSION['cart_array'])<=1)
              {
                   unset($_SESSION['cart_array']);
                   sort($_SESSION['cart_array']);
               }
       else
          {
                   unset($_SESSION["cart_array"][$key_to_remove]);
                   sort($_SESSION['cart_array']);
                   echo count($_SESSION['cart_array']);
         }
     }

        ?>
```

Comment: I don't know PHP, but `$_POST['index_to_remove']=""` looks like an assignment to me.

Comment: in the `'if'` statement at the top, use `$_POST['index_to_remove']!=""`

Comment: Please define what you mean by "not working" and **please** respond to people's comments/answers instead of posting the same question [twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19288522/not-able-to-delete-item-from-cart) or [thrice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19288887/removing-item-from-cart)!

Answer (score 0):

```
&& $_POST['index_to_remove']=""
```

It should be:

```
&& $_POST['index_to_remove'] == ""
```

- `=` Single equal to is used to assign some values to any variable
- `==` compares the values of variables for equality
- `===` checks if the two variables are of the same type AND have the same value

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
if(isset($_POST['index_to_remove']) && $_POST['index_to_remove']="" ) // WRONG
```

TO THIS:

```
if(isset($_POST['index_to_remove']) && $_POST['index_to_remove'] != "" )
```

Please take a look of [THIS](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)