# not able to delete item from cart

Tags: php, arrays, session

i m asking it again so 
this is more specific.

```
     $cartOutput.='<form method="post" action="cart.php">
     <input type="submit"name="deletebtn'.$item_id.'" value="remove"/>
     <input type="hidden" name="index_to_remove" value="'.$i.'"</form>';
```

in this index_to_remove is coming via a hidden input type in the form... i created a form with a remove button and via a hidden output field i passed the index of item that i want to remove from the cart and implemented this code.But its not working.......

```
      <?php
       /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // if user wants to remove an item from cart
         ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
          if(isset($_POST['index_to_remove']) && $_POST['index_to_remove']=!"")
         {  
         //access the array and rum code to remove that array index
             $key_to_remove=$_POST['index_to_remove'];
          if(count($_SESSION['cart_array'])<=1)
          {
               unset($_SESSION['cart_array']);
               sort($_SESSION['cart_array']);
           }
   else
      {
               unset($_SESSION["cart_array"][$key_to_remove]);
               sort($_SESSION['cart_array']);
               echo count($_SESSION['cart_array']);
     }
 }

    ?>
```

Comment: Can you `print_r()` the `$_SESSION['cart_array']` before & after the removal action ?

Comment: Why are you trying to `sort`  `$_SESSION['cart_array']` when you have just `unset` it?

Comment: Doesn't `unset` the whole `$_SESSION['cart_array']`, just an element of it. Still, the question about the need to `sort()` remains. _(edit: oops, I was looking at only the `else` part, I guess he meant to remove an element in `then` too, just missed it...)_

Answer (score 0):

Your html is broken

Change

```
<input type="hidden" name="index_to_remove" value="'.$i.'"</form>';
```

To

```
<input type="hidden" name="index_to_remove" value='$i'></form>';
```

Comment: i sorted this but still item is not removed

Comment: no error but item remains in cart even the echo count($_SESSION['cart_array']);

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
if(isset($_POST['index_to_remove']) && $_POST['index_to_remove']=!"")
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST['index_to_remove']) && $_POST['index_to_remove']!="")
```

as it changes your index_to_remove value to "1" instead of the value from post.

also your html tag is not closed correctly.

Comment: sorry not to ask before, is session_start() called above this code or not ? what the print of $_session show before and after the unset ?

Comment: ya session_start is there at the above

Comment: try using session_destroy, just to check whether it works or its also not working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
if(isset($_POST['index_to_remove']) && $_POST['index_to_remove']=!"")
```

In the second part you have =!""

This evaluates to $var equals not "" and thus returns always true (and sets $_POST['index_to_remove'] to true which is then used in your if) . I believe you were looking for either != or !== which mean is not equal to.